# What is the correct transistor for this switch?

Tags: transistors

Ive provided a crude paint drawing to explain what I need done, basically I need some way to propel a high voltage motor with a low voltage microcontroller, using "pin 2" to trigger a current to run throughout the motor. What is the correct transistor I need?
drawing: http://puu.sh/goxxb/e07b6d10af.png

Comment: Which side of the motor do you need to control it from?

Comment: Am I the only one that doesn't see the drawing?

Comment: What voltage and current does the motor use?

Comment: Which microcontroller, and what voltage are you running it on? What is the maximum current the motor can draw?

Comment: Arduino, 5v motor being abused, 9v. All of which, from my understanding is irrelevant.

Comment: re "All of which, from my understanding is irrelevant." -< that's why you are here and asking questions, presumably. Your current level of understanding is such that it behooves you to politely answer questions if you wish to optimise information gained. If you do not wish to then feel free to respond any way you wish. |You want an NPN transistor with pinout CEB and it should be  areal grunty one to avoid it being destroyed by being abused. | There is a cct drawing program included in the editor you are using here. You need to learn to use it. Doing so will greatly repay the effort taken. |

Comment: If you cannot draw straight lines in paint then using premade shapes and then erasing parts or copying and pasting parts will produce a far far far more professional result. Your current effort is far messier than necessary using the tools you used and will make it hard for people to understand what you want - and many will not bother. .

Answer (score 1):

You want an NPN transistor with pinout CEB and it should be areal grunty one to avoid it being destroyed by being abused.

---

There is a cct drawing program included in the editor you are using here. You need to learn to use it. Doing so will greatly repay the effort taken.

If you cannot draw straight lines in paint then using premade shapes and then erasing parts or copying and pasting parts will produce a far far far more professional result. Your current effort is far messier than necessary using the tools you used and will make it hard for people to understand what you want - and many will not bother.

Instead of:

[image]

I probably last used paint 30+ years ago. 
It seems to be able to do this OK.
This is pretty rough,but ...

[image]

BUT press Ctrl-M and have a play. Very easy to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Cant Really Understand Your Diagram,Considering The That the Left most is Collector that is Connected To the Motor Terminal ... And You Have Connected Base With The Negative Terminal...
**The Basic of BJT is that It Works like an Current Controlled Switch**

So For Switching it On You Have to get it in the Active region/Saturation Region
But What Iam Considered About Is That You Not Provided Any Rating either Of the Motor (Voltage /Current Rating,Type of Motor a)Dc Motor b)Stepper Motor etc)

All I can Say is That BJT Can be Controlled By appling Various Types Of Biasing In the Circuit.

As you Are Using Single Source I Would say you to Use **FIXED Bias/Volage Divider Bias** 

**I Suggest You google Some**
Though Maximum Current You can Get out OF it will be around 1.5 mA max or You may Use some Amplifiers.

If your Motor IS highly Rated in terms Of Power i.e It Requires More than mA 

I Would Suggest You Use Power MOSFETS.
Please Provide Rating And Schematic Diagram Every time.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too vague but I somehow got it now. I am making some wild assumptions here:

- The microcontroller is something like Arduino.
- The motor is not drawing too much of current, assuming under 1 ampere.
- Your motor and microcontroller shares a ground line.

So here is my wild part suggestion. You need two parts:

- `IRL540` logic-level power MOSFET, and
- `1N4007` rectifier diode.

I don't have a computer with me right now so no schematic yet. I am going to describe the circuit in plain English. Ground the source pin of the MOSFET and the negative pole of the battery. One of the ends of the motor as well as the cathode of the diode is connected to the positive terminal of the battery. The other end of both the motor and the diode are tied to the drain pin of the MOSFET. Connect the gate of the MOSFET to the output pin of your microcontroller.

Here the switching element is the MOSFET. The diode, fly back diode, prevents the MOSFET from being zapped by an inductive flyback voltage.